# AES encryption on android device and on .Net server

Tags: android, .net, encryption, cross-platform, aes

I am new to the cryptography world. Please excuse, if this is basic. On Android side, I am trying to do encryption using the following code snippet:

```
    // Get the salt
    SecureRandom random = new SecureRandom();
    byte[] salt = new byte[saltLength];
    random.nextBytes(salt);

    // Secret key
    SecretKey secretKey = getSecretKey(seed, salt);

    // Get Cipher instance for AES with Padding algorithm PKCS5
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");

    // Initialization vector, as CBC requires IV
    byte[] iv = new byte[cipher.getBlockSize()];
    random.nextBytes(iv);

    // Algorithm spec for IV
    IvParameterSpec ivParams = new IvParameterSpec(iv);

    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKey, ivParams);

    // Encrypt the text
    byte[] encryptedTextInBytes = cipher.doFinal(textToBeEncrypted
            .getBytes("UTF-8"));

    return Base64Encoder.encode(encryptedTextInBytes);
```

My question is how do I decrypt on the server side, since salt is completely random. The same problem arises with initialization vector(IV) also. Any ideas? This could be solved by having a hardcoded number for IV and salt, but that defeats the purpose of security.

Comment: Could you show `getSecretKey` too? It may not work as intended.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Neither salt or IV need to be kept secret, so you can simply send them with the ciphertext to the other side. Usually the are prefixed to the ciphertext, but any encoding may be used.

### Code

Below an example that consists of:

- 2 byte salt size
- salt
- 2 byte IV size
- IV
- 4 byte ciphertext size
- ciphertext

---

```
ByteArrayOutputStream blob = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
DataOutputStream dataBlob = new DataOutputStream(blob);

// Get the salt
SecureRandom random = new SecureRandom();
byte[] salt = new byte[saltLength];
random.nextBytes(salt);

dataBlob.writeShort(saltLength);
dataBlob.write(salt);

// Secret key
SecretKey secretKey = getSecretKey(seed, salt);

// Get Cipher instance for AES with Padding algorithm PKCS5
Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");

// Initialization vector, as CBC requires IV
byte[] iv = new byte[cipher.getBlockSize()];
random.nextBytes(iv);

dataBlob.write(iv.length);
dataBlob.write(iv);

// Algorithm spec for IV
IvParameterSpec ivParams = new IvParameterSpec(iv);

cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKey, ivParams);

// Encrypt the text
byte[] encryptedTextInBytes = cipher.doFinal(textToBeEncrypted
        .getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));

dataBlob.writeInt(encryptedTextInBytes.length);
dataBlob.write(encryptedTextInBytes);


// out of scope: add HMAC protection over current contents of blob here
// (or while writing it to dataBlob, also update a HMAC) 

// Base64Encoder encode;
return Base64Encoder.encode(blob.toByteArray());
```

### Protection

For security you would need to add protection of integrity and authentication. That means applying a HMAC over the bytes of the (encoding of the) salt, IV and ciphertext. If the integrity is not protected this scheme is possibly not even good for confidentiality because of plaintext/padding oracle attacks.

For instance:

```
public static String encrypt(int saltLength, byte[] seed, String textToBeEncrypted) throws Exception {

Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
Mac hmac = Mac.getInstance("HmacSHA256");

// Get the salt
SecureRandom random = new SecureRandom();
byte[] salt = new byte[saltLength];
random.nextBytes(salt);

// Secret key
SecretKey secretKey = getSecretKey(seed, salt);

// Initialization vector, as CBC requires IV
byte[] iv = new byte[cipher.getBlockSize()];
random.nextBytes(iv);

// Algorithm spec for IV
IvParameterSpec ivParams = new IvParameterSpec(iv);

// Get Cipher instance for AES with Padding algorithm PKCS5
cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKey, ivParams);
hmac.init(secretKey);

ByteArrayOutputStream blob = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
MacOutputStream macStream = new MacOutputStream(blob, hmac);
DataOutputStream dataBlob = new DataOutputStream(macStream);

dataBlob.writeShort(saltLength);
dataBlob.write(salt);
dataBlob.write(iv.length);
dataBlob.write(iv);

// Encrypt the text
byte[] encryptedTextInBytes = cipher.doFinal(textToBeEncrypted
        .getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));

dataBlob.writeInt(encryptedTextInBytes.length);
dataBlob.write(encryptedTextInBytes);

dataBlob.writeShort(hmac.getMacLength());
dataBlob.write(macStream.getMac());

return Base64Encoder encode(blob.toByteArray());
```

You'll need the streaming class too:

```
public class MacOutputStream extends FilterOutputStream {

    private final Mac mac;

    public MacOutputStream(OutputStream out, Mac mac) {
        super(out);
        this.mac = mac;
    }

    @Override
    public void write(byte[] b) throws IOException {
        mac.update(b);
        out.write(b);
    }

    @Override
    public void write(int b) throws IOException {
        mac.update((byte) b);
        out.write(b);
    }

    public byte[] getMac() {
        return mac.doFinal();
    }
}
```

Note that it's better to use a separate key and don't forget to use a time-static compare when verifying the MAC. I'm not entirely happy about the stream handling, so optimize where possible.

Comment: THank you. Can you point me to a link that adds HMAC, if you can?

Comment: Added code to celebrate my 1000th point for encryption. Encryption posts better be on topic from now on :)